# MEF for composition with static properties

Tags: static, mef

Is it possible to use MEF composition with static properties?

What I do usually is

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
MEFHelper.Compose(obj);
```

and

```
public class MEFHelper
{
    //....
    public static void Compose(object o)
    {
        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        batch.AddPart(o);
        _container.Compose(batch);
    }
}
```

But this works only with instance objects.
Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: why not try a singleton approach? or an export factory?

Comment: Singletons are the antithesis of dependency injection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would question your need to use static properties instead of instance properties. The container is designed in such a way to automatically dispose of instances, which of course it can't do when you're using static properties, as the lifetime and usage of these properties are indeterminate.

*If* you really want to compose a static property, you'll likely need to satisfy the imports on the property itself, e.g.:

```
public static class SomeStaticClass
{
    public static SomeObject Instance { get; private set; }
}

SomeStaticClass.Instance = container.GetExportedValue<SomeObject>();
```

or

```
SomeStaticClass.Instance = new SomeObject();
container.SatisfyImportsOnce(SomeStaticClass.Instance);
```

Realistically though, I'd address your design of your static type to see if you can implement it as a instance type instead.

Comment: Great answer! I couldn't have said it better myself.